# How to let other computers on the same network connect to your node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, ip-address, portforwarding

Hello so i'm trying to learn about node.js and how to use it when making an html5 game. I was wondering how I set it up to allow other computers on the same network to connect to it. Currently on the computer i'm running the server on can connect to it and that kind of defeats the purpose of a multiplayer game. I would assume that allowing others on the network to connect would change to letting any computer on the internet connect to it if I put the server on a host? This is the code I am using he create the server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/index.html");
});
app.use('client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
//Saw on another post for node.js servers to put
//serv.listen(2000, "the ip I want");
//to allow the other computers to connect but
//that did not work when I did it. 
serv.listen(2000);
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know your computer's IP address in order for others to connect to your computer. If you are on Windows you can open up command prompt (by pressing Win+R and typing in `cmd`) and issue the `ipconfig` command. The Ip address will be displayed there. Let's say it is `192.168.0.11`. Then the other users need to open their browser and enter `192.168.0.11:2000` in order to connect to your node.js server. Note that `:2000` is the port which you have specified in your node.js app.

Comment: and if you are on a mac or linux system you can get your ip with 'ifconfig'